# Gvim/Git Plugin error E492: Not an editor command: GitStatus

Tags: git, vim

First, I assume this is a problem with how I installed things and not an issue with the package.

On Windows, I downloaded the zip file for the Git plugin for Vim from
https://github.com/WolfgangMehner/git-support

The zip file is entitled git-support-master.zip and has this tree:

```
git-support-master\doc
git-support-master\git-support
git-support-master\plugin
git-support-master\project
git-support-master\syntax
git-support-master\README.md
```

My $HOME is c:\Users\myuser
and I have c:\Users\myuser\vimfiles.

I interpreted the instructions to mean that I should be able to extract the zip files so that the doc files in the above zip go into the doc directory above. To do this, I have to extract put prune the
git-support-master from the paths.

```
~ vimfiles/
  ~ autoload/
      pathogen.vim
  ~ bundle/
    + delimitMate/
    + nerdtree/
  ~ doc/
      gitsupport.txt
      tags
  ~ git-support/
    ~ doc/
        ChangeLog
    ~ git-doc/
        commands.txt
        compile_changelog.lua
        help_topics.txt
    + rc/
      README.md
  + pack/typescript/start/typescript-vim/
  ~ plugin/
      git-support.vim
  ~ project/
      release.lua
  + syntax/
    README.md
    vimrc
```

My .vimrc is:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set nocompatible
let $ORACLE_HOME='C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client'
set expandtab


nmap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
set autoindent
set sw=4
set clipboard=unnamed
set nu
set noerrorbells
set nohlsearch
set vb t_vb=

"if $OSTYPE=="cygwin"
"    set SHELL=C:\programs\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
"endif
"
"let g:Git_Executable = 'LANG=en_US git'
let g:Git_Executable = 'C:\programs\cygwin\bin\git.exe'
```

When I run things in the git menu, I get errors like this:

```
E492: Not an editor command: GitStatus
```

However, it can find the plugin support.

The Git executable above does exist, and yes I'm using the Cygwin version of it.

I ran the scriptnames command mentioned in the comments but couldn't capture it in a scratchbuffer, but did see that it did not load anything Git plugin related. It loaded the .vimrc, pathogen vim plugins.

I tried :GitHelp and it gave me this:

```
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

These are common Git commands used in various situations:

start a working area (see also: git help tutorial)
   clone             Clone a repository into a new directory
   init              Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one

work on the current change (see also: git help everyday)
   add               Add file contents to the index
   mv                Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink
   restore           Restore working tree files
   rm                Remove files from the working tree and from the index
   sparse-checkout   Initialize and modify the sparse-checkout

examine the history and state (see also: git help revisions)
   bisect            Use binary search to find the commit that introduced a bug
   diff              Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
   grep              Print lines matching a pattern
   log               Show commit logs
   show              Show various types of objects
   status            Show the working tree status

grow, mark and tweak your common history
   branch            List, create, or delete branches
   commit            Record changes to the repository
   merge             Join two or more development histories together
   rebase            Reapply commits on top of another base tip
   reset             Reset current HEAD to the specified state
   switch            Switch branches
   tag               Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG

collaborate (see also: git help workflows)
   fetch             Download objects and refs from another repository
   pull              Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch
   push              Update remote refs along with associated objects

'git help -a' and 'git help -g' list available subcommands and some
concept guides. See 'git help <command>' or 'git help <concept>'
to read about a specific subcommand or concept.
See 'git help git' for an overview of the system.
```

Comment: Use `:scriptnames` to see the names of all scripts loaded by Vim at startup. Try to use that to confirm that `plugin/git-support.vim` is being loaded.

Comment: Try also `:GitHelp`, it will tell you if the plug-in is disabled and the reason why it's disabled. (Quite possibly something to do with the git binary...)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing three different plugin handling methods:

```
~ vimfiles/
  ~ autoload/
      pathogen.vim
  ~ bundle/
```

shows that you are using Pathogen,

```
+ pack/typescript/start/typescript-vim/
```

shows that you are using the new `:help package` feature,

> I interpreted the instructions to mean that I should be able to extract the zip files so that the doc files in the above zip go into the doc directory above. To do this, I have to extract put prune the git-support-master from the paths.

shows that you are trying to install that plugin the "classical" way.

You should choose one method and stick to it…

- The classical way is universally considered messy so you should probably avoid it.
- If you only use a recent Vim, you should probably consider Pathogen as deprecated and opt for either the new "package" method—if you don't mind managing your plugins yourself— or a full-fledged plugin manager like vim-plug.

Answer (score 0):

if it's show in after type wrong command in CMP panel, then just press **esc** and then type again your command, that you want to run.